# Write function with string as argument, creates new string as copy argument, except non-letter is replaced by space

Tags: python-3.x

**Challenge:** Write a function that takes a string as argument, and creates a new string that is a copy of the argument, except that every non-letter is replaced by a space 
(e.g.,"pl@dz&y" is changed to "pl dz y"). 
To write such a function, you will start with an empty string, and traverse the characters of the argument one by one. When you encounter a character that is acceptable, you add it to the new string.  When it is not acceptable, you add a space to the new string. Note that you can check whether a character is acceptable by simple comparisons.For example,  any lower case letter can be found using the test.

**My attempt so far:**

```
def character_replacement( string ):
string_new = ""
for char in string:
    if char >= 'a' and char <= 'z' == True:
        string_new += char
    if char >= 'A' and char <= 'Z' == True:
        string_new += char
    if char >= 'a' and char <= 'z' == False:
        string_new += " "
    if char >= 'A' and char <= 'Z' == False:
        string_new += " "
return string_new

string = input( "Input string, with or without special characters: " )
character_replacement(string)
```

Still struggling to write a working function and how to 'print' or 'return' something.

Comment: You need to use the returned value somehow. e.g. `result = character_replacement(string)` followed by  `print(result)`

Comment: @Duncan: That was really helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`==` is evaluate before `and`. You can wrap your conditions with parenthesis to get the right result:

```
if (char >= 'a' and char <= 'z') == True:
    string_new += char
if (char >= 'A' and char <= 'Z') == True:
    string_new += char
if (char >= 'a' and char <= 'z') == False:
    string_new += " "
if (char >= 'A' and char <= 'Z') == False:
    string_new += " "
```

Or just omit the `==` part altogether, and evaluate the boolean expressions you have:

```
if char >= 'a' and char <= 'z':
    string_new += char
if char >= 'A' and char <= 'Z':
    string_new += char
if not (char >= 'a' and char <= 'z'):
    string_new += " "
if not (char >= 'A' and char <= 'Z'):
    string_new += " "
```

EDIT:
Note this can be made more elegant using the builtin [`isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) method:

```
if char.isalpha():
    string_new += char
else:
    string_new += " "
```

And while you're at it, you could just rewrite the entire method as a comprehension over the string's characters:

```
def character_replacement(s):
    return "".join(c if c.isalpha() else " " for c in s)
```

Comment: That was great, I haven't learned the 'elegant' method yet, so I will stick to the first for now. Thank you!